# cucumber webdriverio datatable

Tags: cucumberjs

**FeatureFile**

```
Feature: Shopper can add an item to their Grocery List

@kk
Scenario: Mutate multiple User Skills at the same time

Then If I click the row "Summary" then I should the following nested information`
  | Tax       | 11.50  |
  | Gratuity  | 4.50   |
  | Total     | 26.59  |
```

**StepDefininition File**

```
Then(/^If I click the row "([^"]*)" then I should the following nested information$/, function (rowName, data){
 cconsole.log("rowName-----"+rowName)
 console.log("data-----"+data)
 data = dataTable.raw();
 console.log(data);`
});
```

**Error Log**
 If I click the row "Summary" then I should the following nested information

```
  dataTable is not defined


  ReferenceError: dataTable is not defined
at World.<anonymous> (/Users/src/__acceptance__/stepDefinition/android/wdio.apps.stepdefs.js:12:3)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (/Users/wdio-cucumber-framework/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.....

Comment: Can you format the code sample so that people can see how your lines break? That can have an affect on how cucumber interprets your scenario.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....
i have edited the code.....
not able to get the datatables data in step definition whatever i am passing in feature files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not overly familiar with Webdriver-io, but it would appear that you are using a variable that is not defined. You are passing `data` into your function, but trying to use `dataTable` which is throwing the error.

Have you tried something like:

```
function(rowName, table) {
  var myData = table.rowsHash();
  console.log(myData);
  console.log(table.raw());
}
```

Unrelated to your question, I would suggest separating your action steps from your validation steps

```
If I click the row "Summary"
Then I should see the following nested information 
  | Tax       | 11.50  |
  | Gratuity  | 4.50   |
  | Total     | 26.59  |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,,,,but no luck

`I should see the following nested information`


     `dataTable.rowsHash is not a function`


      `TypeError: dataTable.rowsHash is not a function`

   ` at World.<anonymous>` 

`(/Users/src/__acceptance__/stepDefinition/android/wdio.apps.stepdefs.js:11:26)`

   ` at new Promise (<anonymous>)`

  `  at new F (/Users/node_modules/wdio-cucumber-framework/node_modules/`core-

`js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)`

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your code on the stepDefinition file:

on the line `data = dataTable.raw();`... there is no variable `dataTable` defined.

Please try the below code:

```
Then(/^If I click the row "([^"]*)" then I should the following nested information$/, function (rowName, dataTable){
        console.log(dataTable);
        var data = dataTable.raw();
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log("Element:" + element[0]);
            console.log("Element:" + element[1]);
        }, this);
});
```

Comment: no success
i am not able to get the datatable in the console.log
error log::


`dataTable------


      I should see the following nested information


      dataTable.raw is not a function



      TypeError: dataTable.raw is not a function
   

 at World.<anonymous> 


(/Users/src/__acceptance__/stepDefinition/android/wdio.apps.stepdefs.js:12:30)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/Users/node_modules/wdio-cucumber-framework/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)
`

Comment: my issue will be resolved if i am able to get the datatable of feature file in step definition.....


console.log("datatable----->>"+datatable)

is returning as blank.....

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked fine for your scenario. Not sure what the problem might be. Could you please share the versions of your npm modules?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,,,,,
actually we build our feature file before execution and put it in dist folder within project.....

while building the feature file,datatable is passing as empty space